# VLOOKUP data from MS excel file in MS Project

Tags: excel, vlookup, ms-project

Completely new to MS Project so apologies in advance for my lack of knowledge. I have an existing Gantt view of a column A and an empty Column B with e.g.

```
Column A (Recipe Steps)    Column B (Ingredients)
Task A
Task B
Task C
Task A
Task B
```

In a separate Excel file I have listed e.g. ingredients that I need for the different tasks.

```
Column A   Column B
Task A      Flour, Eggs
Task B      Sugar, Salt
Task C      Honey
```

Is it somehow possible to use a formula in MS Project for each cell that automatically pulls the data from the excel file and assigns the correct ingredient to the task based on the list? This should lead to

```
Task A     Flour, Eggs (via VLOOKUP?)
Task B     Sugar, Salt (via VLOOKUP?)
Task C     Honey (via VLOOKUP?)
Task A     Flour, Eggs (via VLOOKUP?)
Task B     Sugar Salt (via VLOOKUP?)
```

in the MS project file. I don't want to manually insert all the ingredients for the different tasks, especially if they repeat themselves throughout the gantt chart. If I move the tasks, say switch Row 1 and Row 2, I would want it to automatically look like this without having to copy anything.

```
Task B     Sugar, Salt (via VLOOKUP?)
Task A     Flour, Eggs (via VLOOKUP?)
Task C     Honey (via VLOOKUP?)
Task A     Flour, Eggs (via VLOOKUP?)
Task B     Sugar Salt (via VLOOKUP?)
```

Thanks in advance if you guys could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is this:

1. Create a new blank Excel tab.
2. Copy the Recipe Steps column from Project and paste into cell A1 of the blank Excel tab.
3. Enter VLOOKUP formulas in Column B in the Excel file to populate the Ingredients.
4. Copy the Ingredient values from Excel (Column B), skipping the header row cell. Select the Ingredients column in the Project file and paste.

Comment: Hi Rachel, thanks a bunch for this answer. It kind of appears more like a work-around to me though, is it not possible to insert Formulas in Project that would automatically pull the values from the referenced excel file?

Comment: No, the field formulas are limited to accessing information from the task itself and nothing more. You could write a macro to automate this if the update needs to happen frequently.

Comment: Alright, will try it this way. Thanks again.